# Cannot Find Vertices Counter in Plugin QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I have recently installed the new version of QGIS and can't seem to find the vertices counter in the plugin menu to install. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @user115775! I don't think that plugin has been ported over to QGIS 3 (in fact the [last update](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Vertices_Counter/) was in 2014) :)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me :D  Do you know if there is any other way I can count the vertices in my shapefile using QGIS?

Comment: You could use the **Field Calculator** to create a new integer field with the expression `num_points( $geometry )`. This will give the number of vertices for each feature. You could then use `Vector > Analysis Tools > Basic statistics for fields` on the new field you created to get the sum of the vertices.

Answer (score 2):

Since QGIS is using QT 5 and Python 3, many plugins, if not all, need to be updated. You can refer to this article about the changes in PyQGIS API:

[QGIS 3 is underway – what does it mean for your plugins and scripts?](https://north-road.com/2016/07/11/qgis-3-is-underway-what-does-it-mean-for-your-plugins-and-scripts/)

The existing plugins will not work properly in QGIS 3.0 due to the changes in the QGIS 3.x API compared with the QGIS 2.x API.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! Do you know if there is any other way I can count the vertices in my shapefile using QGIS

Comment: You can use Extract Node tool to convert the vertices to points. You can search for extract node tool in the processing tool bar. Then open the attribute table and you will see the number of points which is actually the vertices. However, if the shapefile is polygon, the output of extract node will contain duplicate vertices as there will be an extra point to close the polygon. Make sure to remove that point.